# Can chrome browser detect file type with file://-protocol?

Tags: google-chrome

With the http(s) protocol, chrome browser usually detects the type of a file even if it has no mime-ending and if the type isn't included in the http response header. Unfortunately, this mechanism doesn't work, if a file without mime-ending is browsed from disk (i.e. protocol: file://).

For instance, I have a html document without mime-ending. If I put the document into the docroot of a web server and browse it, chrome recognizes the html type and renders the document properly. But if I open the the document directly with the browser using the file://-protocol, it is displayed as plain text.

**Question:** Is it possible to configure chrome such that it detects file types also with the file://-protocol? I'm using Chrome Version 69.

**Btw:** Firefox detects the file type with the file://-protocol.

Comment: I’m asking a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52697798/2402790).