# Tell Chrome the content type of an extensionless file loaded under a ‘file’ scheme

Tags: google-chrome, mime-types

I’m loading web documents for test purposes directly from the local file system.
Some of these I’m storing under file names with no extension.
An example is `file:/work/wayic/architec/architectonic`,
which is viewable at [reluk.ca](http://reluk.ca/project/proto-wayic/architec/architectonic).

Firefox 60 treats these files as “text/xml”
which is close enough to render them correctly.
(They are in fact XHTML.)  Chrome 65 used to render them too, if I recall.
But Chrome 69 shows only the source text of the document.

It would help a little if I could learn from Chrome what content type it assigns to these files.
See my comment on a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37321124/2402790).

Looking for solutions, I got no help from the [Modify Content-Type extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-content-type/jnfofbopfpaoeojgieggflbpcblhfhka).
See my problem report there under the *Support* tab.
Nor from the Blink bug reports (open issues), which I searched under these keywords:

```
content type extensionless
content type "no extension"
content type "without extension"
content type extension file scheme
content type extension file protocol
content type extension file system
MIME type extensionless
MIME type "no extension"
MIME type "without extension"
MIME type extension file scheme
MIME type extension file protocol
MIME type extension file system
```

I might end up resorting to an ad hoc, local server (Jetty/Nashorn, or Python http.server)
in order to get a proper rendering out of Chrome.  Or does anyone know an easier way?